# AWS amplify access group by auth user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Hello i added in amplify studio under user management a group admin and added a user to that group. Where i can now access in my code if the current authenticated user is in the group or not?

Answer (score 1):

**On the front-end (react)** you can look at `cognito:groups`. Code snippet below.

Just remember that anyone can go ahead and grant themselves 'admin' on the front-end, so be sure the backend CRUD operations are the source of truth for whether someone is or isn't in a group. e.g. hardcode 'isAdmin = true' in your code, then sign-in as a non-admin user and make sure everything errors out appropriately and you can't do anything malicious.

```js
export const AppRoutes = ({ user, signOut }: { user: AmplifyUser, signOut: (data?: Record<string | number | symbol, any> | undefined) => void }) => {
  const groups: Array<string> = user.getSignInUserSession()?.getAccessToken().payload["cognito:groups"] || []
  const isAdmin = -1 !== groups.findIndex(group => group === "ROLE_ADMIN")

  // You do you...
```

**On the backend**, if you're in a Lambda based GraphQL Resolver, you can take the `authorization` header from the front-end's request and pass it along as the `authorization` header for back-end AppSync and other API calls so they'll execute with the same permissions as the signed in user. (Or alternatively, you may want to `sts:AssumeRole` so the entire lambda operates within the permission scope of that signed in user.)

You can get the auth header from the context passed into the Lambda's handler. It's `ctx` in the following code snippet:

```js
const recipients = await getRecipients({
    authorization: ctx.request?.headers.authorization,
    audience: ctx.arguments.audience,
    username: ctx.identity?.username
})
```

Comment: Thank you the frontend code is what i needed